# How to compute the sum of a variable in R considering ID variable and Index variable and save results in a matrix

Tags: database, r, plyr

Hi everybody I am trying to solve a little dilemma with a data frame in R. I have a data frame with 3 variables `ProductID`, `Price` and `Index`. The structure of my data frame is the next:

```
Tout
   ProductID Price Index
1        001     1     1
2        002     2     1
3        003     3     1
4        004     4     1
5        005     5     1
6        006     6     1
7        007     7     1
8        009     8     1
9        010     9     1
10       001     1     2
11       002     2     2
12       003     3     2
13       004     4     2
14       005     5     2
15       006     6     2
16       007     7     2
17       009     8     2
18       010     9     2
19       011    10     2
20       012    11     2
21       001     1     3
22       002     2     3
23       003     3     3
24       004     4     3
25       005     5     3
26       006     6     3
27       007     7     3
28       009     8     3
29       010     9     3
30       011    10     3
31       012    11     3
32       013    11     3
33       014    11     3
34       001     1     4
35       002     2     4
36       003     3     4
37       004     4     4
38       005     5     4
39       006     6     4
40       007     7     4
41       009     8     4
42       010     9     4
43       011    10     4
44       012    11     4
45       013    11     4
46       014    11     4
47       015    12     4
48       016    12     4
```

In my case `Index` has four values 1,2,3 and 4 and I need to build a 4x4 matrix to save the value of `Price` related to each `Index`. For example when `Index=1` I have to compute the sum of `Price` of all `ProductID` whose `Index` is 1 and they are in `ProductID` for that `Index`. For this case is not difficult because I can make `sum(Tout$Price[Tout$Index==1])` because all `ProductID` with `Index=1` will be in `ProductID` for that index. I am in trouble with the next values of `Index` for 2 I have to fill the second row of a matrix and the first component is the sum of `Price` of all `ProductID` whose `Index` is 2 that are in `ProductID` whose `Index` is 1. The second component of that row is the sum of `Price` of all `ProductID` whose `Index` is 2 that are in `ProductID` whose `Index` is 2. For the third row, first component is the sum of `Price` of all `ProductID` whose `Index` is 3 that are in `ProductID` whose `Index` is 1. The second component of that row is the sum of `Price` of all `ProductID` whose `Index` is 3 that are in `ProductID` whose `Index` is 2 and the third component of this row is the sum of `Price` of all `ProductID` whose `Index` is 3 that are in `ProductID` whose `Index` is 3. The same logic apply for the last row. It is so complex for me building that matrix but if my words aren't enough clear I show this example considering in `DF1` all variables with `Index` 1 and `DF2` all variables with `Index` 2.

```
DF1
  ProductID Price Index
1       001     1     1
2       002     2     1
3       003     3     1
4       004     4     1
5       005     5     1
6       006     6     1
7       007     7     1
8       009     8     1
9       010     9     1

DF2
   ProductID Price Index
1        001     1     2
2        002     2     2
3        003     3     2
4        004     4     2
5        005     5     2
6        006     6     2
7        007     7     2
8        009     8     2
9        010     9     2
10       011    10     2
11       012    11     2
```

To compute the first row of my matrix I used `sum(DF1$Price[DF1$ProductID %in% DF1$ProductID ])`. For the second row in the first component I used `sum(DF2$Price[DF2$ProductID %in% DF1$ProductID ])` and for the second component I used `sum(DF2$Price[DF2$ProductID %in% DF2$ProductID ])`. I don't how to save these values in a matrix and also `Index` can have values until 1500, and create 1500 data frames is not a optim way. That is the reason why `Tout` has all information considering the different values of `Index`. The results of code showed previously should be in a matrix like this:

```
Matrix
    1  2  3  4
1  45
2  45 66
3  45 66 88  
4  45 66 88 112
```

I don't know how to make this because I don't have enough knowlodge about how to operate between rows considering `Index` and `ProductID` to sum `Price`. I would like to make a loop for or maybe a function to create the matrix but I can't find a way. The `dput` code of `Tout`, `DF1` and `DF2` is the next:

```
Tout
structure(list(ProductID = c("001", "002", "003", "004", "005", 
"006", "007", "009", "010", "001", "002", "003", "004", "005", 
"006", "007", "009", "010", "011", "012", "001", "002", "003", 
"004", "005", "006", "007", "009", "010", "011", "012", "013", 
"014", "001", "002", "003", "004", "005", "006", "007", "009", 
"010", "011", "012", "013", "014", "015", "016"), Price = c(1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 11, 11, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 
8, 9, 10, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12), Index = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4)), .Names = c("ProductID", 
"Price", "Index"), row.names = c(NA, -48L), class = "data.frame")

DF1
structure(list(ProductID = c("001", "002", "003", "004", "005", 
"006", "007", "009", "010"), Price = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 
9), Index = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), .Names = c("ProductID", 
"Price", "Index"), row.names = c(NA, 9L), class = "data.frame")

DF2
structure(list(ProductID = c("001", "002", "003", "004", "005", 
"006", "007", "009", "010", "011", "012"), Price = c(1, 2, 3, 
4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11), Index = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2)), .Names = c("ProductID", "Price", "Index"), row.names = c(NA, 
11L), class = "data.frame")
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Are you not just trying to do `aggregate( Price ~ Index , data = tab , sum )`? I don't understand why it's a 4x4 matrix. NM - understand now!

Comment: Yes dear @SimonO101 is a 4x4 matrix because `aggregate` only gives me a summary by `Index`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in three steps, assuming `tout` is your data frame:

```
> library(data.table)
> tout <- as.data.table(tout)
> setkey(tout, ProductID)
> cart <- tout[tout, allow.cartesian = TRUE]
     ProductID Id Price Index Id.1 Price.1 Index.1
  1:         1  1     1     1    1       1       1
  2:         1 10     1     2    1       1       1
  3:         1 21     1     3    1       1       1
  4:         1 34     1     4    1       1       1
  5:         1  1     1     1   10       1       2
 ---                                              
168:        14 46    11     4   33      11       3
169:        14 33    11     3   46      11       4
170:        14 46    11     4   46      11       4
171:        15 47    12     4   47      12       4
172:        16 48    12     4   48      12       4
```

Now `cart` is a cartesian product of `tout` by itself, using `ProductID` as the key.

```
> x <- cart[, sum(Price), by = list(Index, Index.1)]
    Index Index.1  V1
 1:     1       1  45
 2:     2       1  45
 3:     3       1  45
 4:     4       1  45
 5:     1       2  45
 6:     2       2  66
 7:     3       2  66
 8:     4       2  66
 9:     1       3  45
10:     2       3  66
11:     3       3  88
12:     4       3  88
13:     1       4  45
14:     2       4  66
15:     3       4  88
16:     4       4 112
```

`x` is almost what you need, but in a data table (long) form. You need to cast to matrix (wide) form with the help of `avast` from `reshape2` package:

```
> library(reshape2)
> a <- acast(x, Index ~ Index.1, value.var = "V1")
   1  2  3   4
1 45 45 45  45
2 45 66 66  66
3 45 66 88  88
4 45 66 88 112
```

Finally, to set upper triangular part of the matrix to NA:

```
> a[upper.tri(a)] <- NA
   1  2  3   4
1 45 NA NA  NA
2 45 66 NA  NA
3 45 66 88  NA
4 45 66 88 112
```

Comment: Thanks dear @VictorK but is it possible to get lower triangular matrix in your solution because only I need that or fill all over diagonal with NA

Comment: Thanks dear @VictorK you are awesome working with data.table in R.

Comment: Only additional little question dear @VictorK in the example I have only only `Price` variable, in a case where I have 3 `Price` variables `Price`, `Price1` and `Price2` can I apply the same solution but I would have more cartesian products

Comment: Dear @VictorK your solution is good but I don't have the same knowledge than you about data.table. There is any way to compensate you maybe my points. Sorry but two answers are awesome!

Comment: Hey man, +1 this is awesome use of `data.table`. I tried last night, but it was late and I just could not figure it out. Kudos to you Victor K. Great stuff.

Answer (score 1):

```
sTout <- split(Tout, Tout$Index)
crosscount <- function(idx1, idx2) { 
      sum(sTout[[idx1]][['Price']][sTout[[idx2]][['ProductID']] %in% sTout[[idx1]][['ProductID']] ] ) }
 combs <- expand.grid(1:4, 1:4)

 full <- t( matrix( mapply(crosscount, idx1=combs[,1], idx2=combs[,2]), 4,4) )

 full[upper.tri(full)] <- NA
 full
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   45   NA   NA   NA
[2,]   45   66   NA   NA
[3,]   45   66   88   NA
[4,]   45   66   88  112
```

I looked at my code more carefully and thin that I switched the idx values in the summation function: This produces a more complete matrix on the external dataset:

```
sTout <- split(Tout, Tout$Index)
crosscount <- function(idx1, idx2) { 
      sum(sTout[[idx1]][['Price']][sTout[[idx1]][['ProductID']] %in% sTout[[idx2]][['ProductID']] ] ) }
 combs <- expand.grid(1:5, 1:5)

  full <- t( matrix( mapply(crosscount, idx1=combs[,1], idx2=combs[,2]), 5,5) )

  full[upper.tri(full)] <- NA
  full
#-------------------
         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]
[1,] 38327684       NA       NA       NA       NA
[2,] 37933389 37855767       NA       NA       NA
[3,] 37617296 37576066 37860673       NA       NA
[4,] 37097790 37098335 37431261 37449372       NA
[5,] 36541878 36584403 36955598 37044139 37471920
# Just a check to make sure these large numbers made sense.
```

I would be expecting the off-axis values to be necessarily less than the on-axis values in the same colum:

```
> sum(sTout[[1]][["Price"]])
[1] 38327684
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution @DWin that was I amm looking for crack

Comment: But @DWin but your solution doesn't work fine with large data base I replicate your solution over a data frame of 25000 rows and it gives some NA where a sum it is possible to compute. Maybe `%in%` could be affected by bigger size in a data frame

Comment: Doubtful that is the problem. `%in%` has no problems with large vectors. At least you made Victor K. feel better.

Comment: It is so strange because the new ID variable I am testing has a length of 22 character maybe could be that, also I erase possible white spaces with trim from gdata package but I got the same

Comment: Do you get any insight from `with(Tout, table(ProductID, Index))`?

Comment: Dear @DWin is so strange please could you help me please I don't know what happen when I use the function, I allocated my big base in this link https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/83787253/Tout.RData is a R object with my base. I checked with separated sums by index and there is values to sum but when I apply the function it gives me NA in places of matrix where there is values. Please

Comment: Dear @DWin with the function I got this wrong matrix `structure(c(38327683.84, NA, NA, 34949151.54, 34260268.12, NA, 
37855766.98, NA, 35342591.02, 34296356.38, NA, NA, 37860673.05, 
36620060.31, 35324916.02, NA, NA, NA, 37449371.65, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 37471920.36), .Dim = c(5L, 5L))` over the base allocated in the link posted

Comment: And the real matrix is the next `structure(c(38327683.84, 36596788.12, 35012702.9, 33355785.5, 
31656423.89, NA, 37855766.98, 36252355.63, 34572417.87, 32833988.04, 
NA, NA, 37860673.05, 36155550.51, 34378605.22, NA, NA, NA, 37449371.65, 
35652636.58, NA, NA, NA, NA, 37471920.36), .Dim = c(5L, 5L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5")))` I don't have what happen with the function.

Comment: Dear @DWin `Tout` is a data frame with the variables `ProductID`, `Price` and `Index` and with it I compute the matrix can you help me with that I can't find what is wrong the file is not heavy please

Comment: Dear @DWin I checked and finally I found the thing that produces error in the computing of values in your awesome solution `sTout[[idx1]]` must be changed by `sTout[[idx2]]` inside the term of `sum` like this `sum(sTout[[idx2]][['Price']][sTout[[idx2]][['ProductID']] %in% sTout[[idx1]][['ProductID']] ] ) }` Thanks for your help and time

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42750/discussion-between-dwin-and-duck)

Comment: Posted code in chat: Your modification produces the transpose.